# Why isn't my VBE Color Theme being applied?

Tags: excel, vba

I downloaded the github VBE color editor.

Found my VBE7.DLL file here:

[image]

Successfully applied my theme:

[image]

but why isn't the change appearing in the color editor?

[image]

I've retried this on separate occasions, but can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check the [issues](https://github.com/gallaux/VBEThemeColorEditor/issues)?

Comment: @Gustav had to change the foreground/background in regedit, thanks a bunch!

Comment: My VBA is located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX64\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1

Comment: The VBA colour editor works fine on my PC using the location above.

Comment: @freeflow: Thanks. Installed, and got it to work with no issues (Windows 64-bit, Office **32-bit**), the only difference to your path being in `X86` (**32-bit**) instead of `X64` (64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

This works on my laptop but not my desktop. Changing these registry setting did the trick....

```
Dark Theme

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common

CodeBackColors 2 14 4 14 15 2 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 

CodeForeColors 13 4 12 0 6 15 9 6 0 11 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

search the path  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Updates\Download\PackageFiles\83794E93-CE3E-44EF-8A07-8B79C82BFC10\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\VBE7.DLL"
or something similar and your colors will change

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit registry to below

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VBA\7.1\Common**

CodeBackColorsvalue to : 2 7 1 13 15 2 2 2 11 9 0 0 0 0 0 0
CodeForeColors to : 13 5 12 1 6 15 8 5 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

And whenever after the Office is updated automatically, you need to re-edit registry above. Because your setting will be reset.

---

The original author guide to modify registries in regedit as **"OPTIONAL"**.
(https://github.com/dimitropoulos/VBECustomColors)

I guess that it was right when he got the wonderful idea using VBE6 or VBE7 (old VBA).
But after version of VBE was upgraded from 6/7 to 7.1, some things has been changed.

I found that after the Office update, my setting was reset, I have to edit again. It was once or two time in a month. So I modified VBEthemeEditor and named as "O2019" for solving some problem.

After applying dll(hexcode) modification,

- you cannot change font of VBE
- you cannot change font size

I put the MENU to change above in Help tool.
This can help you to edit Registry and set your things.

https://github.com/theangkko/VBEThemeColorEditorO2019